# How to run method once at app launch .NET 6 MVC?

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

How to run a method only once at app launch in .NET 6 MVC application.
This method will use configured services to create default users/roles, seed some configuration data, and register HangFire background jobs.

Comment: Is the real question where to put the calls that used to be in Startup? The HostBuilder and Host classes in a minimal API application have Services and Configuration properties that can be used to add middleware and register services

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry but I couldn't understand your replay. I want to call method once after app.Run() at the program file to check and seed some data.
But all code after app.Run() is never hit or executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run something after `app.Run()`, you might want to register to the `IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted` event. Per MSDN, it is "Triggered when the application host has fully started.".

To register the event use the following code snippet:

```
app.Lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
    create default users/roles,
    seed some configuration data,
    and register HangFire background jobs
)
```